# SWF as backgroundImage in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I'm porting an app from Flex SDK 3 to 4, and .swf -images are turning out to be my major obstacle.

The old app uses Canvas and .swf -files as backgroundImage. Canvas no longer supports backgroundImage, so I'm trying to use BorderContainer instead. However, when I pass the .swf  as backgroundImage to the BorderContainer, it renders white.

Is .swf -files no longer supported as an image format? We've used it because it's vector based and we use Zoom -components and such.

```
//The image is stored in a Class:
[Embed("image.swf")]
public var swfbg:Class;

//Old SDK 3.x code:
<!--mx:Canvas backgroundImage="{swfbg}" /-->

//New SDK 4 code:
<s:BorderContainer id="bc" backgroundImage="{swfbg}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping a `<mx:Image>` inside the `<mx:Canvas>` did the trick.

```
<mx:Canvas>
  <mx:Image source="{swfbg}" />
</mx:Canvas>
```

... turned out to be as simple as it gets.